# How to directly update a record in a database from a form number (Access 2007)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a job-tracking system, and there is a query that returns results of all jobs that are overdue.
I have a form that displays each of these jobs one-by-one, and has two buttons (Job has been completed, and Job not completed). Not completed simply shows the next record.
I cannot find a way to get access to the current record to update it's contents if the "Has been Completed" button is pressed, the closest I can get is the long number which represents the records position in the form.

The VBA to get the index of the record in the form is as follows.

```
Sub Jobcompleted(frm As Form)
    Dim curr_rec_num As Long
    curr_rec_num = frm.CurrentRecord
End Sub
```

This is my first shot at VBA, and after an hour of searching I cannot find anything to solve my problem. 
Am I going about this the entirely wrong way? Working in Microsoft Access 2007

**Further Info** All tables are normalized

Vehicle Table: Contains vehicle_id(pk), as well as rego and model etc

Job Table: Contains job_id(pk), vehicle_id(fk) and other info about what needs to happen, as well as the next occurance date, days between each occurance of the job (all jobs repeat) and other info

Job History Table: Contains job_history_id(pk), job_id(fk), date completed and comments

When the job completed button is pressed, it should create a new entry in the job history table with the current date, any comments and the job id

This is the script I am trying to get working

```
Private Sub Command29_Click()
    Dim strSQL1 As String
    Dim strSQL2 As String
    Set Rs = CurrentRs
    Set db = CurrentDb

    strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO completed_jobs(JOB_ID, DATE_COMPLETED, COMMENTS) VALUES " & Rs!job.ID & ", " & Date
    db.Execute strSQL1, dbFailOnError
    strSQL2 = "UPDATE job SET JOB_NEXT_OCCURANCE = JOB_NEXT_OCCURANCE+JOB_RECURRANCE_RATE WHERE job.ID = Rs!job.ID"
    db.Execute strSQL2, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Note: Line `Set Rs = CurrentRs` is completely incorrect, I believe this is what I need to figure out? This is called on button-press

I am posting an image which shows the form (non-continuous).

@HansUp, I get what you are saying, but I dont quite think it's applicable (I did not provide enough information first time around for you to understand I think)

@sarh I believe this Recordset that you are talking about is what I need, however I cannot figure out how to use it, any hints?

@Matt I am 90% sure I am using a bound form (Like I said, new to Access, been looking at everything people have suggested and learning as I go). There is of course an ID for the job (Just not shown, no need to be visible), but how would I access this to perform an operation on it? SQL I can do, integrating with Access/VBA I am new at

[image: Form for ticking off jobs as they are completed, calls code shown]

Comment: "Am I going about this the entirely wrong way?" I suspect you might be, done properly, Access is easy. Is your form a continuous form? Why can you not get access to the data? Is your recordset complicated so it is not updateable? Have you designed you tables to include a unique id? Did you start your work by reading about relational databases? Have you looked at any of the    Access templates?

Comment: BTW if another person also upvotes your question, you will have enough reputation to post an image of your form, which may be helpful, then again it may not :)

Comment: I'll upvote for the possible image upload, also it appears that you are using a bound form and therefore should be able to include a field with the job's unique number (I sure hope it has one) and then you could reference this text field in your Update SQL.

Comment: Unsure as to how Stack Overflow alerts work, but I have posted more info abouve

Comment: If you append an at sign to the beginning of a person's name, that person will be notified, however, you can only notify one additional person per comment. The owner of the post will be automatically notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your situation, your form is data-bound bound (you can get record index), so - your form already located on this record. If you need to update some field of underlying dataset, you can write something like

```
Me!SomeField = ...
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

If your form has control bound to "SomeField", then the form will be updated automatically.

If this will not help, you can look to a couple of another directions:

1) Update records using SQL code. For example, you have ID of record that should be updated in the form data set, so you can write something like:

```
Call CurrentDB.Execute( _
"UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField = SomeValue WHERE SomeTableID = " & Me!SomeTableID, dbSeeChanges)
```

2) You can look at the Bookmark property - both Recordset and Form has this property, it describes the record position. So you can write something like this (not the best example, but can help you to get an idea):

```
Dim Rs as Recordset
Set Rs = Me.RecordsetClone 'make a reference copy of the form recordset
Rs.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark 'locate this recordset to the form current record
```

Comment: Unsure as to how Stack Overflow alerts work, but I have posted more info above

Comment: @StandOff I beleive record source of your form contains field JOB_ID, so to use it you can write just Me!JOB_ID (no need to add CurrentRs). So strSQL1 (but without Comments) I would rewrite as "INSERT INTO completed_jobs(JOB_ID, DATE_COMPLETED) VALUES (" & Rs!job.ID & ", Date())"

Comment: Just noticed, I've made a misprint in first code snippet - it should be Me!SomeField instead of Rs!SomeField, sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler approach.  I doubt you need to be concerned with the form's CurrentRecord property.  And I don't see why you should need a command button for "Has been Completed" and another for "Has not been Completed".

Add a "Yes/No" data type field to the table which is used by your form's record source.  Set it's default value property to 0, which represents False or No.  Call it "completion_status".  Create a new form using that record source.  Then your form can have a check box control for completion_status.

Newly added records will have False/No as completion_status --- the check box will appear unchecked.  The completion_status for other records in the forms can be toggled between Yes (checked) and No (unchecked) using the check box control.

Comment: Unsure as to how Stack Overflow alerts work, but I have posted more info abouve